# Algorithm design technique

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Design a recursive algorithm for computing 2^n for any non-negative integer n by the formula 2^n = 2^(n-1) + 2^(n-1). 
Prerequisites : There must be an addition operation perform

```
int computepowerOfTwo(int power) {
    if(power == 1) 
        return 1;
    else 
        return (2*computepowerOfTwo(power-1))  + (2*computepowerOfTwo(power-1)) 
}
```

When I supply power as 3 initially it returns 16

Comment: Please show the code you are having trouble with?

Comment: I meant edit the original post and show the code that you have written... :)

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer points out `2^1` is `2`, not `1`.

... but your code should actually stop at `0` instead:

```
if(power == 0) 
    return 1;
```

This is a good opportunity to learn the value of unit testing. A simple test case of the following...

```
for i in range(0, 11):                                                       
    assert computepowerOfTwo(i) == 2 ** i
```

...would show you that (1) you didn't handle the case of `0` and (2) your answer for `2^1` was wrong.

Comment: ohh..  so does the fragment of code return a valid answer after making the change of IF condition

Answer (score 0):

Errors in your code:-

1. `if(power == 1)` you should return `2^1` which is `2`.
2. in `else` part what you are returning is equivalent to `2*2^(power-1) + 2*2^(power-1)` which will result 2^(n+1) which is wrong, so you should just return `2*2^(power-1)`

According to your question your function should be as follow:-

```
int computepowerOfTwo(int power) {
    if(power == 0) 
        return 1;
    else 
        return computepowerOfTwo(power-1) + computepowerOfTwo(power-1);
}
```

Comment: For finding power of 2 you should use above logic.